# input type=file .click() doesn't work on ie8/9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I am having a `<input>` tag whose type is file and code is:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

The code hided it and triggered it using:

```
$j('#file').click();
```

The purpose of doing this is for styling. This works fine on IE10 above and other browsers, but doesn't work for ie8/9. I have tried to unhide the `<input>` field and it works fine but looks really ugly. So the `<input type="file">` does work in ie8/9, but the .click() function doesn't. Any suggestions or walkarounds?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand how the click event helps with styling.

Comment: @DanielA.White That's because input with type file is very hard to be styled. Having another button/link/field which triggers the click() event will let me style the button/link/field instead of the input

Comment: How are you hiding the input field? I tested IE8 emulation mode. Set the visibility of the input to 'hidden' and it still worked.

Comment: @ChaseRocker I used display:none

Comment: I just tested: `<input style='display:none;' type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<span onclick="$('#file').click();">click it</span>` and it worked in IE7-IE9 emulation modes

Comment: @ChaseRocker strange... I changed it into onclick and it doesn't work for me. Not even in ie11 or chrome.

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: @ChaseRocker I am using Jquery 1.9. I know it is a pretty old version. But the project is using it.

Comment: test this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qy9gLtzv/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62084/discussion-between-lance-shi-and-chase-rocker).